# Previous Record based on specific conditions

Tags: hana

My current derived data set looks like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Type_ID |  component  |    timestamp             |  status  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  52     |     G1      |Aug 25, 2014 9:10:47.0 AM |   IN     |
|  53     |     G1      |Aug 27, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM|   OUT    |
|  58     |     G1      |Aug 27, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM|   OUT    |
|  53     |     G1      |Aug 27, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM|   OUT    |
|         |     G1      |Aug 27, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM|   GEN    | 
|  52     |     G2      |Aug 28, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM|   IN     |
|  52     |     G1      |Aug 29, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM|   IN     |
|         |     G2      |Aug 29, 2014 12:11:29.0 AM|   GEN    |
---------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Type_ID |  component  |    timestamp              | status  |  Type_Id | component | timestamp                | status |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         |    G1       |Aug 27, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM |   GEN   |    52    |    G1     |Aug 25, 2014 9:10:47.0 AM | IN     |
|         |    G2       |Aug 29, 2014 12:11:29.0 AM |   GEN   |    52    |    G2     |Aug 28, 2014 11:11:29.0 AM| IN     |
```

So based on the status IN, I would like to get the previous record of the TYPE_ID '', have tried using LAG, but was unable to dynamically fetch the previous record based on STATUS = IN,

Database: SAP HANA,
SQL would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, LAG(TYPE_ID) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP), LAG(STATUS) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP), LAG(TIMESTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) FROM TAB
WHERE STATUS IN ('IN')
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;
```

First we would eliminate all the unwanted records and use lag on the new result set.